# Could non-static member variable be modified in constexpr constructor (C++14)?

Tags: c++, constexpr, c++14

```
struct A {
    int a = 0;
    constexpr A() { a = 1; }
};

constexpr bool f() {
    constexpr A a;
    static_assert(a.a == 1, ""); // L1: OK
    return a.a == 1;
}
static_assert(f(), ""); // L2: Error, can not modify A::a in constexpr
```

- Online Compiler URL: http://goo.gl/jni6Em
- Compiler: clang 3.4 (with -std=c++1y)
- System: Linux 3.2

If I delete L2, this code compiles. If I add L2, the compiler complained "modification of object of const-qualified type 'const int' is not allowed in a constant expression". I am not a language lawyer, so I am not sure whether this is true. However, if it is, why compiler didn't complain anything about L1, since it also called A() as constexpr? Is this a bug of clang? Or did I miss anything?

Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr

BTW, if I change "constexpr A a;" to "A a;" (remove constexpr keyword), L1 failed to compile which is expect. However, the compiler didn't complain about L2 anymore.

Online Compiler URL about this: http://goo.gl/AoTzYx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is just a case of compilers not having caught up to the changes proposed for C++14. Your `constexpr` constructor satisfies all the conditions listed in §7.1.5/4 of [N3936](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/N3936.pdf). Both [gcc and clang fail to compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef25d995b12ef338) your code, but for different reasons.

clang complains:

> note: modification of object of const-qualified type 'const int' is not allowed in a constant expression

which doesn't make much sense, but reminds me of the C++11 restriction that `constexpr` member functions are implicitly `const` (this is a constructor, and that doesn't apply, but the error message is reminiscent of that). This restriction was also lifted for C++14.

gcc's error message is:

> error: constexpr constructor does not have empty body

Seems pretty clear that gcc still implements the C++11 rules for `constexpr` constructors.

Moreover, [N3597](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3597.html) lists this example:

```
struct override_raii {
  constexpr override_raii(int &a, int v) : a(a), old(a) {
    a = v;
  }
  constexpr ~override_raii() {
    a = old;
  }
  int &a, old;
};
```

N3597 was superseded by [N3652](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3652.html), which contains the wording found in the current draft. Unfortunately, the earlier example disappears, but, again, nothing in the current wording says you cannot assign values to data members within the body of a `constexpr` constructor.

### Update (2017-10-03)

clang fixed this, but there has been no new release yet: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=19741
([Compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22%3A3%2C%22filterAsm%22%3A%7B%22labels%22%3Atrue%2C%22directives%22%3Atrue%2C%22commentOnly%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22compilers%22%3A%5B%7B%22sourcez%22%3A%22M4FwTgrgxiAECCsDeAoW6PoJYDs4EMBuNTDKAex1AFMAPABzAQAoBKALln2YAZXkusALywAjIVgBfFJOIoKVEHUawARuXIAbWADM2yEqVgKaDJoiKHSofCCxQA%2BvmDBqYEM3wA6fMJGiAGlgAImDWYiN0MGoQCDAcLh8%2FMWJpFFw4AFt8XH1UdBs7R2dXd2Y9ViDQ8JkUIA%3D%22%2C%22compiler%22%3A%22%2Fopt%2Fclang%2Bllvm-3.4.1-x86_64-unknown-ubuntu12.04%2Fbin%2Fclang%2B%2B%22%2C%22options%22%3A%22-std%3Dc%2B%2B1y%22%7D%5D%7D))

Comment: would it help to assign A::a using initializer syntax instead of in the constructor's function body?

Comment: @NHDaly Yes, of course. clang successfully compiles the code in that case. gcc still fails because `f()` doesn't satisfy the C++11 requirements for `constexpr` functions. The issue here *is* the assignment of the data member within the body of the constructor.

Comment: And that's just because gcc hasn't caught up with C++14 yet, yeah?

Comment: @NHDaly It would seem so, at least when it comes to relaxed `constexpr`

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I understand now that the OP's question is exactly what you described: can we modify a non-const non-static member variable in a constexpr constructor. I'm on board!

Comment: I don't see how that example applies... It is not assigning a value to a data member in the body of the constructor because `a` is a reference, no?

Comment: @ildjarn Aw crap, I totally missed that both the argument and data member are named `a`. You're right about the example, but I think the answer is correct overall, because Richard Smith commented on the bug report corroborating it is indeed a bug.

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean to imply that I disagree with the answer, just the applicability of the code example. :-]