# Change constexpr object member using method fail

Tags: c++, object, gcc, c++14, constexpr

I'm trying to change the value of a `constexpr` object member via a method but i don't understand why it's not working in this specific case :

```
#include <iostream>

struct test
{
    int m_counter = 0;

    constexpr test()
    {
        m_counter++;
        m_counter++;
        increment();
        increment();
        increment();
    }

    constexpr void increment()
    {
        m_counter++;   
    }

    constexpr int value() const
    {
        return m_counter;
    }
};

template<int value>
constexpr void check()
{
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}

// constexpr test t; // value = 3, why ?

int main()
{
    constexpr test t; // value = 5, ok
    check<t.value()>();
}
```

I don't understand why value is 3 when i create object in global scope.
msvc and clang display 5 in both cases but not gcc. Who is wrong?

Comment: [Coliru showing different behavior between gcc and clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/24be6d04e42ddc4c)

Comment: Also, which version of GCC are you using? What flags are you passing to GCC? Which version of Clang, and what flags are you passing to it? Same with MSVC++? Most importantly we need to know if you use C++11 or C++14? `constexpr` constructors and functions behave differently in the two standards (see e.g. [this `constexpr` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) for more information).

Comment: ...it looks like a possible gcc bug to me

Comment: `check` being `constexpr` is ill-formed (NDR); anything involving standard streams can never be a constant expression, regardless of the template argument to `check`.

Comment: @ildjarn: is the compiler required to produce an error by the Standard in that case, or is it OK to simply ignore the `constexpr` as it's happening currently?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo : NDR is 'no diagnostic required', which includes compiler warnings/errors; it's UB.

Comment: Reported as bug [#80039](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80039)

Comment: I use C++14 : 
GCC 6.3 g++ -std=c++14 -Wall
CLANG 3.9.1 clang++ -std=c++14 
MSVC 2015 /std:c++14

Comment: Isn't `increment()` itself ill-formed?

Comment: @Barry: why do you think it is?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Because it's modifying a non-static data member.

Comment: @Barry: that's not something [which is forbidden](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) in C++14 `constexpr` function bodies

Comment: @VittorioRomeo But in the context of initializing a `constexpr` object, it violates http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#2.16

Comment: @Barry: that does indeed look like a potential violation, but I'm not confident about it. If that's the case, it should be added to cppreference's "`constexpr` constructor body restriction list" .

Comment: @Barry: are http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32699007/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23647492 therefore wrong? Or is the violation you're describing happening because `increment()` is being called in `test`'s constructor?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Sorry, what I meant was, the function itself is fine - it's not a violation of the restriction of constexpr member functions. But invoking it, on a constexpr object, shouldn't be.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be a **g++** bug, reproducible from g++ 5.1 up to g++ 7.0. I think it is a bug because the behavior seems nonsensical. I played around with the snippet and I believe that the compiler only executes the first `increment()` call if the variable is global, disregarding the other invocations:

```
constexpr test()
{
    m_counter++; // executed
    m_counter++; // executed
    increment(); // executed
    increment(); // NOT executed
    increment(); // NOT executed
}

// [...] will print 3
```

```
constexpr test()
{
    m_counter++; // executed
    m_counter++; // executed
    increment(); // executed
}

// [...] will print 3
```

```
constexpr test()
{
    m_counter++; // executed
    m_counter++; // executed
}

// [...] will print 2
```

```
constexpr test()
{
    m_counter++; // executed
    m_counter++; // executed
    increment(); // executed
    increment(); // NOT executed
    increment(); // NOT executed
    increment(); // NOT executed
    increment(); // NOT executed
    increment(); // NOT executed
}

// [...] will print 3
```

Basically, only one `increment()` inside the constructor will be executed. Adding more `increment()` calls has no effect. Adding more `m_counter++` instructions will however work properly.

```
constexpr test()
{
    m_counter++; // executed 
    m_counter++; // executed
    increment(); // executed
    increment(); // NOT executed
    m_counter++; // executed
    m_counter++; // executed
    increment(); // NOT executed
    increment(); // NOT executed
}

// [...] will print 5
```

I reported this on the g++ bug tracker as as bug [**#80039**](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80039).