# changing active constexpr union member using construct_at

Tags: c++, c++20, constexpr

I'm trying to change the active member of a `constexpr` union using `construct_at` and get the following error when constructor initializes it's member using initializer list vs. member. Can someone explain why?

```cpp
#include <memory>
struct Z { 
 #if 1  // If this changes to zero it does not compile   
   constexpr Z(int x) : y(x){      
   }  
  #else  
     constexpr Z(int x) {
         y = x;      
   }  
  #endif
   int y;
};

struct W { 
   constexpr W(int x) {
      y = x;
   }   
   W(const W&) {}
   int y;
};

union U { 
   Z z;
   W w;
   constexpr U(int z) : w(z) {
   }   
};

constexpr int func() {
   constexpr U u(10);
   std::construct_at(&u.z, 10);
//   ::new (&u.z) Z(10);
   return u.z.y;
}

int main() {
    static_assert(func() == 1);
}
```

Error:

```
source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:37:26: error: non-constant condition for static assertion
   37 |     static_assert(func() == 10);
      |                   ~~~~~~~^~~~~
<source>:37:23:   in 'constexpr' expansion of 'func()'
<source>:31:21:   in 'constexpr' expansion of 'std::construct_at<const Z, int>((& u.U::z), 10)'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/stl_construct.h:97:14:   in 'constexpr' expansion of '((Z*)<anonymous>)->Z::Z(<anonymous>)'
<source>:8:12: error: modifying a const object '((Z*)this)->Z::y' is not allowed in a constant expression
    8 |          y = x;
      |          ~~^~~
<source>:30:16: note: originally declared 'const' here
   30 |    constexpr U u(10);
      |                ^
Compiler returned: 1
```

Comment: Interestingly clang compiles this https://godbolt.org/z/6d89G3oMK

Answer (score 4):

While I don't know what exactly the case with working/non-working ctors, you have a `constexpr U u(10);` on which you later try to call a modifying function (ctor) by calling `std::construct_at(&u.z, 10);`. What do you expect from trying to modify a `constexpr` object? Remove `constexpr` on the `u` object, it won't make your function less `constexpr`.

Comment: I noticed this also, for me the mystery is why at all original code compiles :)  constexpr implies const for variables... :)

Comment: The original code compiles because it's [ill formed, no diagnosis required](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ndr) `func` never produces a constant expression.

Comment: @ViralTaco_, yep, I was pretty sure that OP has UB in his code I just didn't want to mention it w/o proper proof from the Standard and didn't care to search for the relevant clause from it at the time :)

Comment: Under the hood [`std::cosntruct_at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/construct_at) casts away the `const` qualifier of an object that is declared as `const`. That is why it is ill formed.

Comment: @ViralTaco_ If the function can never be used in a constant expression it is ill-formed, ndr, but if it is used in a context requiring a constant expression then the compiler needs to diagnose it.

Comment: @JánosBenjaminAntal Did you mean to say that it is _not_ ill-formed?

Comment: @user17732522: Technically no, since IFNDR takes priority over diagnosable errors.  In practice, one would expect a diagnostic here from a non-hostile implementation.

Comment: @DavisHerring Thank you for the comment. I was never really sure what the priority technically should be. Is that why https://www.eel.is/c++draft/temp#res.general-6.1 and other points have these weird conditions?

Comment: @user17732522: Indeed, the conditions suppress the NDR rule when a diagnostic should be issued, just like the rules about incompatible declarations *in different translation units*.  It’s [intro.compliance.general]/2.3 that grants such supremacy.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the other answer, `constexpr` on `u` is wrong here. But I will try to say something about the compiler behavior with your code.

`std::construct_at` will construct a new object at the given storage location. However `constexpr` implies `const`, meaning you are trying to create a new object in a const complete object with automatic storage duration. That is not allowed and causes undefined behavior. (The call to `std::construct_at` is however not ill-formed. It may be called with a `const` pointer.)

Since this is happening during the evaluation of an expression that is required to be a constant expression, the question is then whether this makes the expression not a constant expression, i.e. whether the compiler has to diagnose the undefined behavior.

Generally any core language undefined behavior *must* be diagnosed by the compiler. Any standard library undefined behavior *may* be diagnosed by the compiler.

So the question would be here as which the `std::construct_at` call counts. The function itself is specified as equivalent to the corresponding placement-new ([[specialized.construct]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/specialized.construct#2)), except that a special exception is made that `std::construct_at` is allowed in a constant expression unless "the underlying constructor call disqualifies [the expression] from being a core constant expression" ([[expr.const]/6.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.const#6.1)).

Although I don't think it is really clear, I would guess that this is supposed to count as core language undefined behavior since it is not violating any precondition or stated undefined behavior in the library clauses, but rather one stated in the core language clauses.

With that the expression `func() == 1` would not be a constant expression in either of the two versions of the code and the compiler should put out a diagnostic such as GCC is doing in at least one of the shown cases.

However, as I hinted above, I am not confident that my interpretation of the constant expression requirements is the intended one here.

I guess [expr.const]/6.1 could also be read such that the undefined behavior requirement does not apply to a `std::construct_at` call at all, but only to the underlying constructor call. But that does really seem unintended.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong, this is not related.

<s>As it is [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71630244/changing-active-constexpr-union-member-using-construct-at#comment126595593_71630244) in the comments, it works with recent versions of clang. Initially assignment in constexpr constructors weren't allowed in [C++11](https://wg21.link/std11) (check $4 in section 7.1.5), but were allowed in [C++14](https://wg21.link/std14) (same section) in my opinion by [N3652](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3652.html). Check the related changes for (7.1.5)/3 and (7.1.5)/4. So if you are building with C++14 with GCC, then you are struck by a compiler bug.</s>

This answer is heavily based on [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23648778/6639989).

Comment: The code in OP must be compiled with C++20 or later, since `std::construct_at` didn't exist before that. Also, whether assignment is allowed in the constructor is not relevant. As you noticed it has been allowed since C++14. The question is whether the undefined behavior of calling `std::construct_at` on a `const` object needs to be diagnosed (in either of the two cases shown in the question).